# How to create rain dropping effect using animate, positioning and loop

Tags: svg.js

I would have like to render a rain dropping effect, by animating a stroke, changing its position, and making it loop, but **after(path.plot())** is not taken into account in the loop.

How can I integrate position into the loop ?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

var draw = SVG().addTo('#svg').size('100%', '100%');
let lines = [];
let hw = draw.parent().node.clientWidth;
let hh = draw.parent().node.clientHeight;
function getX(){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * hw);}
function getY(){ return Math.floor(Math.random() * hh);}
function getL(x){ return x + Math.floor(hw/20);}
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  let x = getX();
  let y = getY();
  let length = x + Math.floor(hw/20);
  let path = draw.path("M"+x+" "+y+"L"+length+" "+y);
  path.attr({ 'stroke': 'black', 'stroke-dasharray': length, 'stroke-dashoffset': length});
  let dash = x+','+length;
  let run = path.animate({'duration': 5000, 'delay': i*500}).attr({ 'stroke-dashoffset': 0 }).after(
    function(){
      x = getX();
      y = getY();
      length = getL(x);
      path.plot("M"+x+" "+y+"L"+length+" "+y);
      path.attr({ 'stroke': 'black', 'stroke-dasharray': length+' '+length, 'stroke-dashoffset': length});
    }
  ).loop(5000, false, 500);
}

});
```

Comment: Once you define an animation it is absolute in its values. Even if you Change the dash offset, it will be reseted by whatever you defined in the animation. If you want a new starting point you need a new animation. Plot should work though because you don't a animate it

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply, i need to figure out something else then. Yes, plot function works, if I set an other animation behind, it will change it position.

Comment: Maybe this is a bug. Consider opening an issue on the repo

Comment: Just to confirm. considering `path.animate().plot(<randoms>).animate()`, path should not change its position on the second animate ?

Comment: If the second animation comes after the first (and the first is not looped = both animations don't change the same properties at the same time) it should work